How can you save Java Module Descriptor files back into Java language?
In jGRASP I write (mostly basic) work in Java. Essentially I changed the language for a couple files to be "Java MD" on accident, it serves no purpose for the task at hand. I get an expected name error to save as "module-info.java` instead of class name which is required for organization. I assumed this could be undone in jGRASP if it doesn't alter the file.
i'd like to save the program without copying the lines into a new file, but it will be a workaround as of writing.

"Settings" > "Compiler Settings" > "File", then change the language and "OK".
